# Create Facebook Sidebar / Navigation in Xcode/iOS5?

Tags: xcode, facebook, ios5, navigation, sidebar

Does anyone know how to create that sidebar/navigation that Facebook uses in their app. It would work perfect for the app I'm planning on making. But I can't put this in my mock up design if i'm not sure how to go about it.

Here is a picture from the App Store of the Facebook app with the sidebar open:

[image]

How do they implement this?

Comment: This is answered several times. Please search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [JTRevealSidebarDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo) in your project.

Answer (score 0):

There are various code available.
You can try

1. [ios_facebook_style_navigation](https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation)
2. [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
3. [JTRevealSidebarDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo).

Answer (score 0):

I use MFSideMenu but JASidePanels is also a good one.
The can be found right here https://www.cocoacontrols.com